# Inverting the Propagator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus, dirac-equation, linear-algebra, dirac-matrices

I would like to know how I can invert the following expression:
$$
S^{\mu\nu}=(\!\!\not{p} -m)\eta^{\mu\nu}+\gamma^{\mu}\!\!\!\not{p}\gamma^{\nu}+m\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu} \ ,
$$
to get $(S^{−1})^{\mu\nu}$. Please if possible explain step by step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141916/discussion-between-william-martens-and-lima).

Answer (score 3):

As you are not giving any further context of your question, the first part of my answer will just be an educated guess of the physical background of the posed problem. On top of that, the task to invert the given expression seems to be some sort of homework exercise, so I shall not work out the final answer but show you the general strategy that will finally lead to the solution.

1. Your title is misleading. The expression $S^{\mu \nu}(p) = (p \! \! \! / -m)\eta^{\mu \nu} +\gamma^\mu p \! \! \! / \gamma^\nu + m \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu$ cannot be a propagator as it has no poles in $p^2$. $S^{\mu \nu}(p)$ is nothing else than the Fourier transform of the differential operator $D^{\mu \nu}= (i \partial \! \! \! /-m) \eta^{\mu \nu}+ \gamma^\mu i \partial \! \! \! / \gamma^\nu + m \gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu$. Finding the inverse of $S^{\mu \nu}(p)$ is thus equivalent to the determination of the Green function of the differential operator $D^{\mu \nu}$. As a Green function is not uniquely determined (one may always add a solution of the homogeneous equation), certain boundary conditions have to imposed. Given the physical context, most probably Feynman boundary conditions are tacitly assumed being enforced by the usual $i \epsilon$ prescription $m \to m-i \epsilon$. In short, $S^{-1}$ is a propagator and not $S$!
2. It is obvious that the differential operator $D^{\mu \nu}$ acts on a field $\psi_\nu(x)$ (a spinor with a Lorentz index) with the (free) field equation $D^{\mu \nu} \psi_\nu(x)=0$ derived from the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi}_\mu D^{\mu \nu} \psi_\nu$. The field $\psi_\mu(x)$ is a (massive) Rarita-Schwinger field describing particles with spin $3/2$.
3. A systematic procedure to find the inverse of $S^{\mu \nu}(p)$ is based on the well known fact that the 16 matrices $\{ \Gamma^a \} =\{\mathbf{1}_4, \gamma^\mu, \sigma^{\mu \nu} (\mu < \nu), \gamma_5, \gamma^\mu \gamma_5\} $ ($a=1,\ldots,16$) form a basis of the space of complex $4 \times 4$ matrices. $S^{\mu \nu}(p)$ can thus be written as a linear combination of the matrices of this basis, the explicit expression given by $S^{\mu \nu}(p)= (p \! \! \! /-m) \eta^{\mu \nu} +(p^\mu \delta^\nu_{\,  \alpha} +p^\nu \delta^\mu_{\, \alpha} -p_\alpha \eta^{\mu \nu}) \gamma^\alpha+ i \varepsilon^{\mu \nu \alpha \sigma} p_\sigma \gamma_\alpha \gamma_5$. Its inverse, $S^{-1}$, is now determined by starting from the ansatz $(S^{-1})_{\nu \rho} = \sum\limits_{a=1}^{16} c_{a \nu \rho} \Gamma^a$ and imposing the condition  $S^{\mu \nu} (S^{-1})_{\nu \rho} = \delta^\mu_{\, \, \rho} \mathbf{1}_4$. The resulting products $\Gamma^a \Gamma^b$ are again written as linear combinations of the $\Gamma^c$ matrices which finally allows to determine the expansion coefficients $c_{a \nu \rho}$. In all intermediate steps, the well known formulas for the traces of products of gamma matrices turn out to be helpful. As such a calculation easily turns into an exercise in self torture, the use of an algebraic computer code is highly recommended.